# getting error in draggable gridview for vertical scrolling in android

Tags: android, gridview

i want draggable gridview with proper scrolling. can anyone help me ?
I found library but in that vertical scroll is not working..
I have tried this one.. 
https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

```
public void setContainer(PagedDragDropGrid container) {
    this.container = container;
}

private int positionOfItem(int pageIndex, int childIndex) {
    int currentGlobalIndex = 0;
    for (int currentPageIndex = 0; currentPageIndex < adapter.pageCount(); currentPageIndex++) {
        int itemCount = adapter.itemCountInPage(currentPageIndex);
        for (int currentItemIndex = 0; currentItemIndex < itemCount; currentItemIndex++) {
            if (pageIndex == currentPageIndex && childIndex == currentItemIndex) {
                return currentGlobalIndex;
            }
            currentGlobalIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this link...
https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

it provide draggable grid items....

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.